# function boundary tracing in OSX w/ DTrace

Tags: macos, dtrace

I'm having an awfully hard time trying to trace all functions with dtrace (or dapptrace) in OSX 10.11.3.

From [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/819-5488/gcgkk.html#gcglh) on dtrace (dated 2006), it looks like this simple script should be useful for tracing function entry and exit:

```
pid$1::$2:entry
{
    self->trace = 1;
}

pid$1::$2:return
/self->trace/
{
    self->trace = 0;
}

pid$1:::entry,
pid$1:::return
/self->trace/
{
}
```

How can I run this against a short lived program, like hello world to start?  I would have guessed:

```
➜ sudo dtrace -s userfunc.d

dtrace: failed to compile script userfunc.d: line 1: invalid probe description "pid$1::$2:entry": Undefined macro variable in probe description
➜ sudo dtrace -s userfunc.d -c a.out

dtrace: failed to execute a.out: file is set-id or unreadable [Note: the '-c' option requires a full pathname to the file]

➜ sudo dtrace -s userfunc.d -c `pwd`/a.out

dtrace: failed to compile script userfunc.d: line 1: invalid probe description "pid$1::$2:entry": Undefined macro variable in probe description
➜ sudo dtrace -s userfunc.d -c `pwd`/a.out execute

dtrace: failed to compile script userfunc.d: line 1: invalid probe description "pid$1::$2:entry": Undefined macro variable in probe description
```

The second example tracing libc works if I change the reference to libc.so to libsystem_c.dylib.

It appears that dapptrace fails as well.

```
➜ sudo dapptrace ./a.out
dtrace: invalid probe specifier
...
: probe description pid16290:a.out::entry does not match any probes
```

Adding `-U` prints a whole lot of garbage, not sure if it's even useful (didn't see my call to puts, or any fprintf or write).

Now I know that DTrace and in particular dtruss are definitely not broken in OSX.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably late, but the main problem seems to be that you are not specifying correctly the $1 arg:

> The $1 macro variable expands to the first operand on the command line. This macro variable **is the process ID for the process to trace**.

If you use `-c`, then instead of pid$1 you could use pid$target, which automatically uses the PID of the spawned process.

As for dapptrace, it seems to have a problem in OS X: you have to add a -Z to the dtrace invocation inside of the dapptrace script (line 258). https://www.mail-archive.com/dtrace-discuss%40opensolaris.org/msg03808.html